# How to add crosshair vertical line in line graph using Core Plot framework?

Tags: ios, iphone, cocoa-touch, core-plot

I am using core plot framework for drawing the line graph in iPhone and it is working fine.I am displaying system time on X- axis and Temperature on Y- axis.I need to draw the cross hair vertical line that indicate the selected value on the line graph. for example
[image]

I would highly appreciate if someone can give me some suggestion to solve this issue.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: As a last resort, you can create your own UIView subclass that you place over this plot, and draw it yourself.

Answer (score 2):

You can use another axis or scatter plot to draw the line. Using an axis is simpler if all you need is a single horizontal or vertical line. Set all of the tick and grid line styles to `nil` and use the `orthogonalCoordinateDecimal` to position it in the correct location. There is a demo using a scatter plot to draw a crosshairs over the selected point in the Mac version of the *CPTTestApp* example app.